# Optaplanner: Performant implementation to known on the anchor which is the last entity of its chain

Tags: optaplanner

Which is the performant implementation to known on the anchor which is the current last entity of its chain?

Right now I traverse all the chain up to the end to get it which is O(n) in terms of performance.

Is there a way to attach a `VariableListener` on the Anchor to be notified en every chain update?

NOTE: My entities have a reference to previous and next (the later implemented by a `VariableListener` on the entity)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `@CustomShadowVariable`  with the `source` set to:

- the `@PlanningVariable` (for example `Customer.previousStandstill`) to be notified of every chain update
- the `@AnchorShadowVariable` (for example `Customer.vehicle`) to be notified of every planning entity switching to another anchor

Comment: Thanks for your help and quick response (as usual)! I didn't know it is possible to attach custom @AnchorShadowVariable listeners.

Comment: I tried to specify a custom variable listener to @AnchorShadowVariable however no `variableListenerClass` is present in that shadow variable type